# Tensorflow – ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are x and y for 'z'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Нашел образец кода, запихнул в jupyter не работает сейчас копаюсь в офф документации пока ни х не понял возможно это связано с версией у меня 2.10.0

```
# Создание модели
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(window_size, X.shape[1])),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# Компиляция и обучение модели
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(time_series_dataset.batch(32), epochs=50)
```

ошибка

```
      8 # Компиляция и обучение модели
      9 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])
---> 11 model.fit(time_series_dataset.batch(32), epochs=50)
ValueError: in user code:
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 10 and 5 for 
'{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](mean_squared_error/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze, Cast)'
 with input shapes: [?,10], [?,5].
```

Comment: Посмотрите вопросы справа от вопроса, в колонке "Похожие".